# "A lesser amount of x and y" or "lesser amounts of x and y"?

Tags: grammar

> A lesser amount of x and y is needed to satisfy his wants.

vs.

> Lesser amounts of x and y are needed to satisfy his wants.

Which one is grammatical? They both sound right to me.

Comment: Then why do you think they're wrong?

Comment: The fact that one can use a plural and singluar form at the same time?

Comment: You aren't doing that here. "Amount is" and "Amounts are" don't use them at the same time. Each uses the right one.

Answer (score -1):

Both are horribly inflated. Why “amounts”? And is “wants” really wanted? All that is needed is:

> Less x and y are needed to satisfy him.

Less is more.

Comment: The down vote suggests that some inflated person has been offended by my criticism of inflated sentences. Sad. I gave style advice for free — others would charge for it.